# How to use preact-compat with server side rendering in rollup + buble setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup, rollupjs, preact

I have a preact app which is using rollup + buble. I need to use another component [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/react) which uses React. I am trying to create alias within my rollup build file. For the client side, it works flawlessly however when building on the server side, it fails. My plugin section within my rollup build config is as below :-

```
plugins: [
    alias({
      'react': path.resolve('./node_modules/preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.es.js'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.es.js')
    }),
    nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, browser: true }),
    commonjs({ include: ['node_modules/**'], namedExports: { 'preact-redux': ['connect', 'Provider'] } }),
    replace({ '__CLIENT__': true, 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }),
    images,
    buble({ jsx: 'h', objectAssign: 'Object.assign' }),
    !isDev && uglify(uglifyConfig) // uglify slows builds
  ]
```

I came across an [issue](https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/299#issuecomment-280499913) where it says there are issues while using preact-compat on a server side app and it was suggesting to use module-alias as an alternative. So i tried giving the below module-alias in my node server file :-

```
require('module-alias').addAliases({
  'react': 'preact-compat',
  'react-dom': 'preact-compat'
})
```

Even after doing that, i still get the below error :-

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at r (/my-app/node_modules/react-text-mask/dist/reactTextMask.js:1:145)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my-app/node_modules/react-text-mask/dist/reactTextMask.js: 1:315)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

Comment: The alias part with module-alias should be at the very beginning of your server code.

Comment: @thangngoc89 Its at the beginning of my node server file.

Comment: Without further detailsof your code, I can't know how to fix this. Does it work without react-text-mask?

Comment: I made it work by register the alias on `package.json`, no luck using `.addAliases({...})` idk why

Comment: @AlfredCrosby Still not able to get it working. Can you share how you have the aliases in your package.json file. Does the path structure matter in that?And where have you hooked up the below registering?
`require('module-alias/register');`

Comment: ` "_moduleAliases": {
    "react": "node_modules/preact-compat",
    "react-dom": "node_modules/preact-compat"
  },` that's my alias on `package.json`. But I have an issue, it's only working on dev mode. When I try build my server code using webpack, it won't work.